# Qt emit signal after widget is closed

Tags: qt, user-interface, qt5

I have a child QDialog, when a button is pressed from it a socket is opened from QtConcurrent, and if there's an error an alert dialog is shown.
But if the user closes the child QDialog to return to the main window the signal cannot be received by the child QDialog slot.
I tried to broadcast the signal to parentWidget, but the program crashes, because this->parentWidget() doesn't exist anymore.
I use this code to emit the signal and connect it to the slot

`connect(this, SIGNAL(errorTcpSignal(QString)), this, SLOT(displayTcpError(QString)));`

```
 connect(&t, QOverload<QAbstractSocket::SocketError>::of(&QAbstractSocket::error),[=](QAbstractSocket::SocketError err){
        emit errorTcpSignal("Error while changing game settings \n" + QVariant::fromValue(err).toString());
    });
```

Is there a way to solve this issue?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:
emit the signal from the child widget, but set the connection from the father widget.